# phpexcel freeze row and columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to freeze the top row and the first 3 columns in a worksheet, using PHPExcel.

I can freeze the row without any problem:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');
```

Or I can freeze the column without any problem:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('D1');
```

But when I try to use both, the first gets over-written by the second.

Is there any way to use both on the same sheet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I assume you're trying to Freeze columns and rows both.

`freezePane` will obviously overwrite any previous parameters you might have given to it.

As per your current scenario, I see that you're trying to freeze the **top row** and the **left-most 3 columns**

Try this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('D2');
```

This will freeze **Row 1** and **Columns A,B & C**

This should get your work done!

***Note:*** `freezePane` works exactly how you use it in MS Excel. You select a cell and select Freeze. And it freezes whatever rows are above it, and the columns which are left to it.

Comment: Good solution. Also, for people who prefer them, there's also the function freezePaneByColumnAndRow($col,$row)

Comment: freezePaneByColumnAndRow throws an error in Excel 2016 that the file is corrupt. freezePane works

Answer (score 2):

```
// Use this
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;


// Now, 
$spreadsheet    = new Spreadsheet();


// Freeze Rows Above (A3)
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A3'); 

// Set Worksheet Name
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($subject);
```

> I am using this In My Laravel project.

> For Composer You can Use this.

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

// Create new Spreadsheet object
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

(...)

// with coordinates:
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(7,4);

// with cell name:
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('D7');