# How to freeze headers and a set of columns using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to freeze my page headers and columns like so:

[image]

I can freeze my headers absolutely fine and dandy:

```
    $highestRowCount = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumnCount = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    $sheet->freezePane( "{$highestColumnCount}2" );
```

But when I then add another freeze on the columns:

```
    $sheet->freezePane( "D{$highestRowCount}" );
```

It breaks excels ability to scroll...

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: `$sheet->freezePane('{$highestColumnCount}{$highestRowCount}');` Tried that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpexcel freeze row and columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423964/phpexcel-freeze-row-and-columns)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can only have one single freezePane on any individual worksheet, so you set the address to cover both horizontal and vertical, e.g.

```
$sheet->freezePane( "D2" );
```

Comment: Spot on.. and from the development team themselves :D what an honour :D

Answer (score 2):

Freeze fourth column and first line :

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet(); //get current active sheet (first sheet)

$sheet->freezePane('D2');
```

And if you want to Freeze first column and first line:

```
$sheet->freezePane('B2');
```

Freeze first column only:

```
$sheet->freezePane('B1');
```

Freeze till second column:

```
$sheet->freezePane('C1');
```

Freeze first line(row) Only:

```
$sheet->freezePane('A2');
```

Freeze til second line(row):

```
$sheet->freezePane('A3');
```