# How to freeze upper row with PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I use PhpSpreadsheet to generate an excel file with php, and would like to freeze the first row. Is it possible with this component? I have read through the help at  https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ , but it doesn't seem to support this function.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423964/phpexcel-freeze-row-and-columns

Comment: Yes this solved the issue. Thank you very much.